# Twig template adds JSON-LD duplicate

Tags: twig, json-ld

I've got this homepage and when I execute my template, the JSON-LD script is duplicated inside my page (1 in the HEAD and 1 in the middle of the page).

I just don't understand why this script is running another time in the middle of the page...

So here is my code: The `header`, where I introduced the JSON-LD script and the the `bodyContent` block where you can find the page content.

```
{% block header %}
    {% block head_javascript %}
        <script type="application/ld+json">
            {
                "@context": "http://schema.org",
                "@type": "WebSite",
                "url": "",
                "description": "",
                "name": ""
            }
        </script>
    {% endblock%}
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyContent %}
   {# TAG | SELECTION #}
    <div>

        <h2> {{ 'title' }} </h2>
        <p> {{ 'desc' }} </p>

    </div>

    <div>

        <div>

            <h1>{{ 'create.title' }}</h1>
            <p>
                {{ 'create.desc' }}
            </p>

            <div>

                <div>
                    {% set texte %}{{ 'create.step.one' }}{% endset %}
                    {% set svg %}svg:cursor-mkp.svg.twig{% endset %}
                    {% set number %}1{% endset %}
                    {{ include(':step.html.twig') }}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {% set texte %}{{ 'create.step.two' }}{% endset %}
                    {% set svg %}svg:mkp.svg.twig{% endset %}
                    {% set number %}2{% endset %}
                    {{ include('idea-step.html.twig') }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="{{path('path.mkp')}}">
                <button>{{ 'create.button' }}</button>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I've found this error with the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). Indeed, I've seen that there was the same structured data twice.

Comment: Unclear. We can't know with only the snippet of the `JSON-LD` post your base/main template at least..

Comment: Ok i've add my base page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help someone :

From my controller, my header block is generating more code than I coulded see and I was not able to check this before I just move my jsonld script out of the header block.

Now it's working well and I do not have 2 times the same snippet.

```
{% block header %}
{% endblock %}

{% block head_javascript %}
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "WebSite",
            "url": "",
            "description": "",
            "name": ""
        }
    </script>
{% endblock%}
```